# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get' Flask api

Tags: python, flask

Вылетает ошибка:

> next_call_date_str = env.get("callback_time", None)
> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

Как можно исправить?

```py
def write_env_data(
                   env: dict,
                   dialog_uuid: str = '',
                   project=None):
    next_call_date_str = env.get("callback_time", None)

    ex = get_ex(db_expired=next_call_date_str)
    if not ex:
        return f"Incorrect callback_time {next_call_date_str}", 403
    response: tuple = set_to_redis(
        dialog_uuid=dialog_uuid,
        env=env,
        ex=ex,
        project=project,
    )

    return response
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка вам подсказывает, что у объекта `env` нет метода `get`, так как это строка.

То есть при вызове функции `write_env_data()`  в параметр `env` вы передаете строку. Следовательно надо смотреть выше по иерархии на вызов данной функции и передать ожидаемый словарь, а не строку.

**NB** Определение в функции типа данных вот так:

```py
def func(parameter: dict):
....
```

не имеет никакой смысловой нагрузки или валидации для `parameter`, кроме как подсказать, что в данный параметр передается определенный тип данных.

Comment: вызов такой идет
return write_env_data(
                         dialog_uuid=dialog_uuid,
                         env=env,
                         project=project)

Comment: @AleksandrFetisov так вот перед данным вызовом используйте `print(type(env))` и я более чем  уверен, что там не словарь, а строка. Следовательно, приведите тип данных `env` к словарю до вызова самой функции

Comment: <class 'str'> дает

Comment: @AleksandrFetisov о чем я и говорю. Если там строка вида `json`, используйте `import json`, а затем `env = json.loads(env)`. Если же нет, то либо поищите информацию как это сделать, а если не найдете, задайте новый вопрос с новыми входными данными

Comment: то есть такого вида
return write_env_data(
                         dialog_uuid=dialog_uuid,
                         env = json.loads(env),
                         project=project)

Comment: @AleksandrFetisov лучше вынесите в отдельную строку кода, чем загружать вызов функции, хотя это тоже релевантно

Comment: спасибо!
теперь правда другая ошибка, но сейчас будет гуглить)

Comment: @AleksandrFetisov на здоровье, можете пометить ответ как полезный и принять его. Так как тут нет далее темы для обсуждения и новых ответов. А при наличии другого вопроса, создавайте новый. Здесь такая модель: один вопрос -> конкретный ответ

Comment: @AleksandrFetisov +1 за отзывчивость и понимание))